# Recharts is not working for the React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts, victory-charts, react-starter-kit

I have an issue with handling chart libraries.

Step by step

1. Create an empty project

> `$ npx create-react-app chart-demo --template typescript`

2. Add Recharts

> `$ yarn add @types/recharts`

3. Run the project

> `$ yarn start`

It shows the following error.

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'recharts' in '\chart-demo\src'
```

*FYI, it's not only for recharts but for several libraries. Fortunately, I found [victory chart](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-chart) is working*

**It's really fresh a new project, just added `recharts` only.

Please help me to figure out this issue.**

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "chart-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.15",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't install recharts, you only installed its type definitions.

Try:

```
yarn install recharts
```

---

When you install a `@types/<package-name>` package, you aren't installing any runnable code. You are just installing the type definitions for a package that doesn't provide it's own types. You still need to install the package itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that you've installed `rechart` instead of `recharts`. make sure you install the correct package (`recharts`).

Answer (score 0):

**Mar 2021** - Similar issue:

**Error:**

> error An unexpected error occurred:   "ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> _
> copyfile
> _
> 'C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-recharts-scale-0.4.4-8d6d1fce49cb617ee047601c6b261f3e5ca7f2c7-integrity\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.min.js\main.js'
> ->
> 'C:\code\KF\mono-repo\kfadvance-frontend-dev\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.min.js\main.js'".

**Reason:**

Below two paths were files, previously.
But now, they are directories.

```
\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.js
\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.min.js
```

**Fix:**

1. Delete the files (or, rename to a different file name)

   `\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.js`
   `\node_modules\recharts-scale\umd\RechartsScale.min.js`
2. Run `yarn`